# How to configure the connection from venv to postgresql?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, python-venv

I am new to python.

I am creating some programs that do an ETL and save the tables in a postgresql database.
The connection to the database is done in the following way.

I have a **settings.ini** file where I have the variable:

```
bdd_link = postgresql://postgres:adrian123@localhost:5432/prueba
```

In a **config.py** file I have the variable:

```
from decouple import AutoConfig
link_bdd = config("bdd_link")
```

And in a **sql_con.py** file I have the following:

```
from config import link_bdd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy_utils import database_exists, create_database

def acceder_bdd():
    url_bdd = link_bdd
    if not database_exists(url_bdd):
        create_database(url_bdd)
        engine = create_engine(url_bdd, echo=False)
```

This all works when I run it normal.

But when I do it inside a virtual environment (venv), the create_tables() function, which in turn uses the acceder_bdd function, which I use to create tables inside postgresql, gives me the following error:

engine.connect().execute(f"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {table}")

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'connect'

It's like the create_engine(url_bdd, echo=False) method isn't working, and it makes me think that database "settings" don't work this way inside a virtual environment.

Comment: Well, you only created the `engine` object only when `if not database_exists(url_bdd)` evaluates to True. Moreover, you didn't include the full traceback.  You also want to verify that your theory about the configuration not working by checking what got assigned to `link_bdd`, chances are it is what you expect but something else that you haven't checked resulted in `engine` being assigned with the value `None`.